# cannot use geokit or Geocoder inside property_web_builder engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, rails-geocoder, geokit

I was customizing the [property_web_builder](https://github.com/etewiah/property_web_builder) engine for getting nearby results using Geokit or Geocoder gem, but can't use any of it.
getting undefined method 'gecoded_by' using 'Geocoder' gem and undefined method 'acts_as_mappable' for 'geokit-rails' gem.

Here is what I was doing -
For geokit-rails

```
module Pwb
  class Prop < ApplicationRecord
    translates :title, :description
    globalize_accessors locales: I18n.available_locales
    attribute :title
    attribute :description
    acts_as_mappable :default_units => :miles,
    :lat_column_name => :latitude,
    :lng_column_name => :longitude
```

For Geocoder

```
module Pwb
  class Prop < ApplicationRecord
    translates :title, :description
    globalize_accessors locales: I18n.available_locales
    attribute :title
    attribute :description
    geocoded_by :complete_address
    after_validation :geocode
```

When I try finding the results in rails console after adding the engine on project as described in readme. I get these results.

> p = Pwb::Prop.first
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `acts_as_mappable' for #Class:0x007f04ecda5118
>   from (irb):1

similiar for geocoder

> p = Pwb::Prop.first 
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `geocoded_by' for #Class:0x007f04ecda5118 from (irb):1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added gem to application gemfile instead of pwb engine's gemfile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of property_web_builder here. Glad you found the answer. You can always create an issue on the github repo if something like this happens again.